# AngularJS: Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Создал povider в модуле core:

```
var coreModule = angular.module('core.vkApi', []);

coreModule.provider('VkApiProvider', function() {

    var settings = {};

    this.setSettings = function(vkSettings) {
        settings = vkSettings;
    };

    this.$get = [function() {
        return {
            test: function() {
                console.log('test');
            }
        };
    }];
});
```

В app.module.js добавляю модуль core в зависимости:

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'core',
    'analyticsMenu',
    'networkChoose'
]);
```

В app.config.js пишу:

```
angular.
module('phonecatApp').
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', 'VkApiProvider',
    function config($locationProvider, $routeProvider, VkApiProvider) {
        ...
    }
]);
```

И в итоге получаю:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: VkApiProvider
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модуль называется *'core.vkApi'* это название и должно быть использовано в зависимостях

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'core',
    'core.vkApi'
    'analyticsMenu',
    'networkChoose'
]);
```

---

Основная ошибка: при использовании метода *provider* к названию автоматически добавляется *Provider*.

Таким образов в методе *config* нужно использовать

```
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', 'VkApiProviderProvider',
```

либо убрать этот суффикс в определении

```
coreModule.provider('VkApi', function() {
```

```js
var coreModule = angular.module('core.vkApi', []);

coreModule.provider('VkApiProvider', function() {

  var settings = {};

  this.setSettings = function(vkSettings) {
    settings = vkSettings;
  };

  this.$get = [
    function() {
      return {
        test: function() {
          console.log('test');
        }
      };
    }
  ];
});

coreModule.provider('VkApi', function() {

  var settings = {};

  this.setSettings = function(vkSettings) {
    settings = vkSettings;
  };

  this.$get = [
    function() {
      return {
        test: function() {
          console.log('test');
        }
      };
    }
  ];
});

angular.module('test', ['core.vkApi'])
  .config(function(VkApiProviderProvider, VkApiProvider) {
    console.log('С дописанным суфиксом', VkApiProviderProvider);
    console.log('Без суффикса в определении', VkApiProvider);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test"></div>
```

[Ссылка на пример из справки](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe)

Comment: Но ведь остальные сервисы работают как надо, почему? Проблема только с этим злосчастным провайдером.

Comment: На всякий случай проверил - не помогает.

Comment: @ИльяБизунов, обновил ответ

Comment: а `.factory` и `.service`, получается, ничего не добавляет? Ведь используя их я всегда сам писал, соответственно `nameFactory` и `nameService`.

Comment: @ИльяБизунов, тут все зависит от конкретного места использования. Даже вот так: в секции config обязательно к указанному имени дописывать Provider